# How to change jre of eclipse product via repository update

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

We have a cdt eclipse product. We work on windows XP and Bundle JRE for this environment with the product option in launching page of product file does not work...

We want to upgrade our jre via update. We have the JRE in our previous bundle and dont want to copy paste new version manually but we want to do it via update repository... How can we do this ? Is it possible to change the JRE via update ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a p2 update site (possible with eclipse tycho) and these are the steps you need (kind of tedious)

1. Open a new workspace
2. Create a new feature project -> new -> plugin development > feature
3. Give your feature an ID and name
4. import your new jre bundle into the workspace and increment the version to what it should be.
5. go to your feature.xml in the feature project, click "included plugins" and add the jre bundle plugin.
6. Next in the site.xml (or category.xml based on what version of eclipse you have) of the update site you created select site map editor view, create a new category called "JRE Runtimes" or something like that. under that category add the feature you created using the wizard.
7. Then to build the p2 site In the sitemap view of the site.xml editor click "build all"
8. After that completes you can refresh the update site plugin and you will see a folder for plugins/features/ and other resource files for the update site. Then you can do a couple of things, the best is to zip that entire update site and upload to an FTP site or HTTP Site in its extracted state and if you give your users the URL they can go into the app, go to help -> install new software. Add a new update site using the URL you provide. Once they do that they can view the features to install and clicking on the feature you created will install the updated jre bundle version.

There are some more gotcha's though, if you have plugins in the app that specify a specific version of the jre bundle it will not use the new one. Best way is to not specify a version and it will use the newest one. Also going forward you should do this same process for your entire app so users can get updates using the p2 provisioning framework. If you want to automate the building of the update site look into eclipse tycho which can also upload the p2 site for you every release.

Hope that helps - Duncan Krebs

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed instructions, but we dont use feature in our product. Can touchpoint be an alternative solution. This link says there is copy function in touchpoint. http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html

Comment: Hey, the problem I think you have is p2 update sites require the use of features you can't just add a plugin, so giving users a update site URL without a feature won't work, will take a look at your link above.